# matplotlib adjacent subplots: adding colorbar changes size of a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to plot a figure consisting of 5 x 6 subplots, all of which I want to be adjacent, i.e. share their x and y axes.

I also want to add a colorbar to the rightmost plot in each row, which is normalized for all the subplots in that row.

I add the colorbar using:

```py
   divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
   cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.15)
   fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

However, adding the colorbar changes the size of the subplot, and it's not sticking to the other subplots any more. Here is a sample output:
[image: sample output, generated with the program below]
How can I get it to not change dimensions when I'm adding a colorbar?

Here is the example for the code that generates the image above:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable, axes_size 

# border limits for plots
lowlim = 0.43
uplim = 0.52
nx = 10


kernels = ['cubic_spline', 'quintic_spline',
        'wendland_C2', 'wendland_C4', 'wendland_C6']




#========================
def main():
#========================


    eta_facts = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

    nrows = len(eta_facts)
    ncols = len(kernels)

    Ay_list = [[None for c in range(ncols)] for r in range(nrows)]



    #--------------------------------
    # Loop and compute As
    #--------------------------------
    dx = (uplim - lowlim)/nx

    for row, eta in enumerate(eta_facts):

        for col, kernel in enumerate(kernels):

            A = np.zeros((nx, nx), dtype=np.float)

            for i in range(nx):
                for j in range(nx):
                    A[j,i] = row + np.random.random()/10 # not a typo: need A[j,i] for imshow

            Ay_list[row][col] = A




    #------------------------------------
    # Now plot it
    #------------------------------------

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.5*ncols, 3.5*nrows))

    axrows = []
    i = 1
    for r in range(nrows):
        axcols = []
        for c in range(ncols):
            if r > 0:
                if c > 0:
                    axcols.append(fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i, 
                            aspect='equal', sharex=axrows[r-1][c], sharey=axcols[c-1]))
                else:
                    axcols.append(fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i, 
                            aspect='equal', sharex=axrows[r-1][c]))
            else:
                if c > 0:
                    axcols.append(fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i, 
                            aspect='equal', sharey=axcols[c-1]))
                else:
                    axcols.append(fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i, aspect='equal'))
            i+=1
        axrows.append(axcols)



    cmap = 'YlGnBu_r'

    lw = 2


    for row in range(nrows):
        axcols = axrows[row]

        minval = min([np.min(Ay_list[row][c]) for c in range(ncols)])
        maxval = max([np.max(Ay_list[row][c]) for c in range(ncols)])


        for col, ax in enumerate(axcols):

            im = ax.imshow(Ay_list[row][col], origin='lower', 
                vmin=minval, vmax=maxval, cmap=cmap,
                extent=(lowlim, uplim, lowlim, uplim),
                #  norm=matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm(1e-3),
                zorder=1)

            # only plot colorbar for last column

            if col==len(kernels)-1:
                divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
                cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.15)
                fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)


            ax.set_xlim((lowlim,uplim))
            ax.set_ylim((lowlim,uplim))


            # cosmetics
            if col > 0:
                left = False
            else:
                left = True
            if row == len(eta_facts)-1 :
                bottom = True
            else:
                bottom = False

            ax.tick_params(
                axis='both',        # changes apply to the x-axis
                which='both',       # both major and minor ticks are affected
                bottom=bottom,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
                top=False,          # ticks along the top edge are off
                left=left,          # ticks along the left edge are off
                right=False,        # ticks along the rigt edge are off
                labelbottom=bottom, # labels along the bottom edge are off
                labeltop=False,     # labels along the top edge are off
                labelleft=left,     # labels along the left edge are off
                labelright=False)   # labels along the right edge are off


            if row==0:
                ax.set_title(kernels[col] + ' kernel', fontsize=14)
            if col==0:
                ax.set_ylabel(r"$\eta = $ "+str(eta_facts[row])+r"$\eta_0$")


    fig.suptitle(r"Some title", fontsize=18)
    plt.tight_layout(rect=(0, 0, 1, 0.97))
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    plt.savefig('for_stackexchange.png', dpi=150)
    plt.close()

    print('finished.')

    return





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.15)` steals space from the subplot. In case that is undesired, you need to define `cax` in a way that it does not steal space, possibly using a gridspec.

Comment: Potentially, the use of `axes_grid1` toolkit module is easier in this case, see e.g. [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_axes_grid.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the following the comments from user ImportanceOfBeingErnest and using axes_grid1, I could make it work.

The main difference: For each row, I define a `ImageGrid` object:

```
    axrows = [[] for r in range(nrows)]
    i = 0
    for r in range(nrows):
        axcols = [None for c in range(ncols)]

        axcols = ImageGrid(fig, (nrows, 1, r+1),
                    nrows_ncols=(1, ncols), 
                    axes_pad = 0.0,
                    share_all = True,
                    label_mode = 'L',
                    cbar_mode = 'edge',
                    cbar_location = 'right',
                    cbar_size = "7%",
                    cbar_pad = "2%")
        axrows[r] = axcols
```

And then, at the right place in the code, I add the colorbar with

```
axcols.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)
```

Here is the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable, axes_size 
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

# border limits for plots
lowlim = 0.43
uplim = 0.52
nx = 10


kernels = ['cubic_spline', 'quintic_spline',
        'wendland_C2', 'wendland_C4', 'wendland_C6']




#========================
def main():
#========================


    eta_facts = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

    nrows = len(eta_facts)
    ncols = len(kernels)

    Ay_list = [[None for c in range(ncols)] for r in range(nrows)]



    #--------------------------------
    # Loop and compute As
    #--------------------------------
    dx = (uplim - lowlim)/nx

    for row, eta in enumerate(eta_facts):

        for col, kernel in enumerate(kernels):

            A = np.zeros((nx, nx), dtype=np.float)

            for i in range(nx):
                for j in range(nx):
                    A[j,i] = row + np.random.random()/10 # not a typo: need A[j,i] for imshow

            Ay_list[row][col] = A




    #------------------------------------
    # Now plot it
    #------------------------------------

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.5*ncols+1, 3.5*nrows))



    axrows = [[] for r in range(nrows)]
    i = 0
    for r in range(nrows):
        axcols = [None for c in range(ncols)]

        axcols = ImageGrid(fig, (nrows, 1, r+1),
                    nrows_ncols=(1, ncols), 
                    axes_pad = 0.0,
                    share_all = True,
                    label_mode = 'L',
                    cbar_mode = 'edge',
                    cbar_location = 'right',
                    cbar_size = "7%",
                    cbar_pad = "2%")
        axrows[r] = axcols



    cmap = 'YlGnBu_r'

    lw = 2


    for row in range(nrows):
        axcols = axrows[row]

        minval = min([np.min(Ay_list[row][c]) for c in range(ncols)])
        maxval = max([np.max(Ay_list[row][c]) for c in range(ncols)])


        for col, ax in enumerate(axcols):

            im = ax.imshow(Ay_list[row][col], origin='lower', 
                vmin=minval, vmax=maxval, cmap=cmap,
                extent=(lowlim, uplim, lowlim, uplim),
                #  norm=matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm(1e-3),
                zorder=1)

            ax.set_xlim((lowlim,uplim))
            ax.set_ylim((lowlim,uplim))


            # cosmetics
            if col > 0:
                left = False
            else:
                left = True
            if row == len(eta_facts)-1 :
                bottom = True
            else:
                bottom = False

            ax.tick_params(
                axis='both',        # changes apply to the x-axis
                which='both',       # both major and minor ticks are affected
                bottom=bottom,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
                top=False,          # ticks along the top edge are off
                left=left,          # ticks along the left edge are off
                right=False,        # ticks along the rigt edge are off
                labelbottom=bottom, # labels along the bottom edge are off
                labeltop=False,     # labels along the top edge are off
                labelleft=left,     # labels along the left edge are off
                labelright=False)   # labels along the right edge are off


            if row==0:
                ax.set_title(kernels[col] + ' kernel', fontsize=14)
            if col==0:
                ax.set_ylabel(r"$\eta = $ "+str(eta_facts[row])+r"$\eta_0$")
        axcols.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)


    fig.suptitle(r"Some title", fontsize=18)
    plt.tight_layout(rect=(0, 0, 1, 0.97))
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
    plt.savefig('for_stackexchange.png', dpi=150)
    plt.close()

    print('finished.')

    return





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which produces this image:

[image: results]

Comment: Good lord this should be easier